# raspberry pi 3 & win10 IoT - how to sign up as windows insider

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I've followed all the instruction in Noobs but i can't go on with the install procedure becouse they ask me to sign up as windows insider.
I've win10 on my home pc and i understand how to set up the windows insider procedure. But i don't want to set up my pc to receive beta update..i only want to download and install Win10 ioT core on my RPI 3.

I've already tried searching on Microsoft help site but without succes. There isn't a form in which sign up for Windows Insider Program.

[I'm stuck at this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxRXK.png)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

To setup raspberry pi you could follow instruction provided by Scott Hansellman [Setting up Windows 10 for IoT on your Raspberry Pi 2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpWindows10ForIoTOnYourRaspberryPi2.aspx)

Have fun

Comment: URL provided works as expected on my machine :). However according to Windows Dev Documentation for Raspberry Pi 3 currently available builds are only from Insider Preview. Your machine will be not setup as Insider Preview only valid Windows 10 IoT version will be downloaded.

Comment: Exactly...that's the point. I've to sign up as insider but i don't know how. And i don't want to enable this feature on my home-pc which i'm using for work.

Comment: You should signup for Insider Preview in [NOOBS tool](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) during setup on Raspberry

Comment: Yes..i should but it seems i can't. I'm stuck at the page i've attached in my first post.

Comment: SOLVED! It seems it's necessary to wait validation by microsoft. Today, after 1 day, it works. I've done nothing different. Only wait.

Comment: Hmm... Strange in my case I need to wait only few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Go via the Windows 10 IoT developer route here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot

Then from the 'Get Started' option choose your device as a Pi 3 and select 'Flash Onto a Blank SD Card'. The resulting option will then lead you to using the IoT Dashboard application available for Windows Desktop. This is a really handy way to setup and manage devices.

Finally you should arrive at the following page offering the option to get the insider preview OS and sign up with an MSDN account etc...

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/GetStarted/rpi3/sdcard/insider/getstartedstep2

If you then want to know how best to control your Pi 3 running Windows IoT Core check out this blog post: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/06/controlling-your-windows-10-iot-core-device/

Answer (score 0):

Just go and Sign up Here https://insider.windows.com/en-us/ 
After Signup, you can get all windows insider build OS, SDK, Tools